# where command lists gls for where ls

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

I was trying to list the paths of the `ls` executables using `where ls`, which should list all locations where the ls executables exist along with the alias of `ls`.

I've also installed coreutils through homebrew with the prefix `g` so the command `ls` from coreutils will be `gls`.

When I run the command `where ls` I got the following output.

```bash
$ where ls                                                                                                                                                             
ls: aliased to command exa -F --icons
/usr/local/bin/gls
/bin/ls
/bin/ls
```

My question is why `/usr/local/bin/gls` is listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem. I have [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) and enabled [gnu-utils](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/gnu-utils) plugin.

When I disabled the `gnu-utils` plugin, the list did not contain `gls`.